# I'm trying to run Docker container from built image but get registry error

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster, docker-registry

I cannot get the registry container for a Jhipster app to run.  I'm following the instructions from https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#7    I'm at the step of executing the command

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up
```

and this is the error

```
docker-jhipster-registry-1  | 2023-01-03 15:09:23.932  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'OAuth2SecurityConfiguration' defined in file [/app/classes/tech/jhipster/registry/config/OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied depe
ndency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creatin
g bean with name 'org.zalando.problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parame
ter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.
autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parame
ter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.secur
ity.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
method 'setClientRegistrationRepository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bea
n with name 'clientRegistrationRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAut
h2ClientRegistrationRepositoryConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanI
nstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory
method 'clientRegistrationRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with t
he provided Issuer of "http://keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster"
docker-jhipster-registry-1  | 2023-01-03 15:09:24.019 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
docker-jhipster-registry-1  |
docker-jhipster-registry-1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'OAuth2SecurityConfigur
ation' defined in file [/app/classes/tech/jhipster/registry/config/OAuth2SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through const
ructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.zalando.
problem.spring.web.advice.security.SecurityProblemSupport': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebM
vcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org
.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.conf
iguration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setClientRegistrationR
epository' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientRegistratio
nRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/oauth2/client/servlet/OAuth2ClientRegistrationRepository
Configuration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed
to instantiate [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository]: Factory method 'clientRegistrationRepo
sitory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to resolve Configuration with the provided Issuer of "http://
keycloak:9080/realms/jhipster"
```

any ideas what may be happening?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you using Keycloak for authentication (rather than Okta).  Check to see if Keycloak is running with 'docker ps'.  If it isn't you can start it with:

```
docker-compose -f src/main/docker/keycloak.yml up -d
```

From the gateway application's (or monolith's ) root directory.